# Configure router on another router

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router

I have an old router that I want to use it for VoIP, since it has phone output ports.

I have disabled DHCP and the router gets connected to the working WAN router via Ethernet. It works in the sense that the router's WiFi is working and giving access to internet, but VoIP is not working.

After going to the CLI interface, I tried to ping the WAN router and it works. However pinging other devices do not work. I guess there is no default gateway configured.

Is what I'm trying feasible ?
I 've CLI access but I'm not sure if anything can be configured there.

[image: Router Commands from telnet]

Comment: Does the router not have an HTTP interface? Configuration is usually a lot simpler with this.

Comment: What's the make and model of the device you are trying to configure?

Comment: There is but I don't see something that could help there. Only basics.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart TG788vn, probably some Thomson Speedtouch clone, judging from the similar CLI. https://fccid.io/RSE-TG788VNV2/User-Manual/User-Manual-1924670.

Comment: I found system,config,WANMode= ETH but it does not seem to work

Comment: https://support.aa.net.uk/Router_-_TG582N_-_Using_an_external_modem, but still not working.